# Unchanged bootstrap template not rendering as mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, viewport, metatag

[image: Standard bootstrap not rendered as mobile] I started working with
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

If I look at the file locally with chrome dev tools it renders perfectly as mobile. But when I upload the template to a webserver and look at it again, the meta viewport tag is ignored and the page ends at coverpicture height: 100%. Same is true on a real ipad/iphone (I can't scroll any further down unless I click a link (the page goes a little crazy first)).

I have made 0 changes to the template. Downloaded from official page, unpacked, uploaded to webserver, the end..
What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Many Thanks
Kind regards

Comment: did your meta tag is like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 1):

check the meta and viewport.
check in the head if you have the below script if not add it then refresh and see.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```